# How can we create a VIEW in transaction with other queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, transactions

I have a query generator, I need to check existence of a view and recreate it. In addition I want to create a table before of view creation. How can I do these works in a transaction.

note: create view must be the first statement in a batch.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your statements with [GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

```
begin transaction    

create table xx ....

go

create view v_xx
as 
....

go

commit transaction
```

Comment: I run this query in my c# code. I add \n\r after GO but this not work for me.

Comment: @masoud - `GO` is not understood by SQL Server it is just used as a batch delimiter in some of the tools. You can delete the `GO` statements  and use `EXEC('create view v_xx')` instead.

Comment: @masoudramezani, Good to see you got it working. Another option for you would be to control the transaction from your C# code and execute one batch at a time. Finishing up with a commit or doing a rollback in your exception handler in case something went wrong.